# Navbar become transparent and fixed to top when scroll down

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my nav bar to look like this site.

http://bootstraplovers.com/templates/assan-v2.3/main-template/index.html

When I'm scrolling, the nav bar of that template becomes transparent and becomes fixed to the top. I want my nav bar to do the same. I'm new to HTML and CSS and also to bootstrap. Can someone give me ideas how to do it or any clues?

This is my nav bar:

[image: screen shot of navbar]

---

```css
.navbar-header{
   height: 74px;
 }
 
 .navbar-toggle{
   position: relative;
   top: 15px;
 }
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  font-weight: 590;
  color: #949494;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 35px 2px 45px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: border-bottom-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom-color 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  }
  .nav.navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .nav.navbar-nav > li.active a{
  color:#a92419;
  border-bottom-color: #a92419;
   }
   .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
  color: #a92419;
  background-color: white;
 }
  .navbar-default{
  background-color:#fff;
  margin: 0;
 
  }
  .nav>li>a {
  position: relative;
  }
 .navbar-default .navbar-right > li > a {
 padding: 0 30px;
 margin-right:6px;
  }
  .nav.navbar-nav > li{
  display: :inline-block;
  }
  .nav.navbar-nav{
  list-style-type:none;
  }
  .nav.navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
  color:#a92419;
    border-bottom-color: #a92419;
   }
   .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
   background-color:#a92419;
   margin:0 0 4px;
   width: 25px;
   height: 5px;
   margin-right: 13px;
   }
   .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover{
   background: none;
   }
   button.navbar-toggle{
   background:none;
   border:none;
   color:#000; 
   margin: 0px;
 }
 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
 }
 
 .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  color:#a92419;
 }
 .dropdown-menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 3em;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
 .dropdown:hover a.dropdown-toggle {
   border-bottom-color: #a92419;
   color:#a92419;
 }
 .top-bar-dark {
   background-color: #a92419;
 }
 
 .top-bar-light {
   background-color: #f3f3f3;
 }
 .top-bar-light .top-dark-right li {
   border-color: #ddd;
 }
 
 .top-bar-light .top-dark-right li a:hover {
   color: #32c5d2;
 }
 .top-bar-socials {
   line-height: 30px;
   padding-top: 5px;
 }
 .top-bar-socials:after {
   display: table;
   clear: both;
   content: "";
 }
 .top-bar-socials a {
   margin: 0px 8px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size:18px;
   color: #fff;
 }
 
 .top-dark-right {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
 }
 
 .top-dark-right li {
   line-height: 40px;
   border-left: 1px solid #932015;
   padding: 0px 10px;
 
 }
 
 .top-dark-right li, .top-dark-right li a {
   color: #d7d7d7;
   font-size: 12px;
 }
 
 .top-dark-right li i {
   margin-right: 5px;
 }
 
 .top-dark-right li a:hover {
   color: #fff;
 }
 a.login{
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 .fa-facebook:hover{
   color:#3b5998;
 }
 .fa-twitter:hover{
   color:#1dcaff;
 }
 .fa-linkedin:hover{
   color:#007bb5;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.6.3/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="top-bar-dark">
  <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-7">
  <div class="top-bar-socials">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Governor-Andres-Pascual-CollegeNavotas-City/344134628983014?fref=ts">
   <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/official_gapc">
   <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/governor-andres-pascual-college-in-navotas-city">
   <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-5 text-right">
  <ul class="list-inline top-dark-right">
    <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> gapc_school@yahoo.com.ph</li>
    <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (02) 282-9036</li>
    <li><a href="#" class="login"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
 <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
   </button>
   <img class="img-responsive" src="images/brandz.png">

 </div>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About us</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="#">History</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Mission and Vision</a>
   </li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Admissions</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Faculty Portal</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using bootstrap's inbuild tool `affix` by adding `data-spy` to your navbar like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="150">
```

And add this to your CSS:

```
.navbar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); <-- Replace with the color you want
}
```

**P.S.** Replace `150` with height of the `top-bar-black` div.

Comment: the width of the navbar when i scroll is not 100% sir. only about 80% width.

Comment: Oh I forgot to add `width:100%;` to `.navbar.affix`. Sorry about that. Answer updated.

Comment: hello sir it already worked :) but can i make it transparent tho?

Comment: i already replace the background color by transparent. but that transparent is OA. its not white transparent hmm.

Comment: This should give you a transparent white color --> `background-color: rgba (255,255,255,0.5);` actually. Try changing the `0.5` to different values to match the opcaity level that you want.

Comment: It's not changing haha. but thank you very much sir :) cheers hehe.

Comment: That's so weird. Can you replicate what you have done so far in  here -> https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/109/ so I'll check it out??

Comment: how can i save it?

Comment: Just click the `update` button once you have copied the codes and then copy and paste the new link here.

Comment: You added a space after `rgba`. It should be like this--> `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);`

Comment: My mistake actually. Sorry again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113685/discussion-between-nethken-and-andrew-lyndem).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, just set the 'XXXXX' data with your values.
$navDiv is the jQuery Object of the navigation container div, e.g. $('#nav'), 'YOUR_TOP_OFFSET' is the offset of your pinned navbar, so in your case '0'.
'YOU_TOP_VAL' is the value in pixels to scroll, thatnavbar should be fix, so in your case the height of the div above the navbar, you can do it automatically of course with $('.top-bar-socials').height(), or with the original offset of the "navDiv".

```
        var  $navDiv = 'YOUR_NAVBAR';

        function removePinClasses(object) {
          object.removeClass('pin-top');
          object.removeClass('pinned');
        }

        function updateElement(object, scrolled) {
            // Add position fixed (because its between top and bottom)
            if ('YOUR_TOP_VAL' <= scrolled && !object.hasClass('pinned')) {
              removePinClasses($navDiv);
              object.css('top', 'YOUR_TOP_OFFSET');
              object.addClass('pinned');
            }

            // Add pin-top (when scrolled position is above top)
            if (scrolled < 'YOUR_TOP_VAL' && !object.hasClass('pin-top')) {
              removePinClasses($(this));
              object.css('top', 0);
              object.addClass('pin-top');
            }
          });
        }

        updateElement($navDiv, $(window).scrollTop());
        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
          var $scrolled = $(window).scrollTop() + 'YOUR_TOP_OFFSET';
          updateElement($navDiv, $scrolled);
        });
```

With CSS:

```
.pin-top {
  position: relative;
}

.pinned {
  position: fixed !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some idea. If **only Chrome and Firefox** will be fine for you.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="nav"></div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0px;
}
.top {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #222;
}
.slider {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #fed;
}
.nav {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    top: 0;
}
```